# How to bind selectedIndex of a select element with vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

why can't I bind the `selectedIndex` property of a `select` element to a variable with vue and how can I achieve to do it anyway?

I'm trying to synchronize two `select` elements in a page by the index of the selected `option`. In order for the synchronization to work, the index must be propagated in both ways: from any element to a vue data variable and from this vue data variable to both elements.

At first, I tried to use `v-bind.sync`, but since it didn't work, I decided to try the explicit way via `v-bind` and a `v-on:change` event handler method. While updating the data variable in the event handler works, the binding doesn't. This is my example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="app">
        <select v-bind:selectedIndex="index" v-on:change="indexChanged">
            <option>zero</option>
            <option>one</option>
        </select>
        <select v-bind:selectedIndex="index" v-on:change="indexChanged">
            <option>zero</option>
            <option>one</option>
        </select>
        Index stored in vue-app: {{ index }}
    </div>

    <script>
        let app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                index: 0,
            },
            methods: {
                indexChanged: function(event) {
                    this.index = event.target.selectedIndex;
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

One clue I noticed, is that PyCharm complains where I try to bind `selectedIndex`. The tooltip says: "Unrecognized attribute or property name". (It also says "vue@3.2.0", although version 2.5.17 is in use here, which puzzles me.)

[image: PyCharm complaining]

Anyway, I can perfectly get and set the value via the JS console in the browser and the `select` actually updates its selected option according to the new index.

```
>> document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].selectedIndex
<- 0
>> document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].selectedIndex = 1
<- 1
```

I looked for another property that holds the selected index' information and the only one I found was `.option.selectedIndex`. I don't know how to bind this either.

The only way I'm seeing now, is to bypass vue's reactiveness and take the sledgehammer approach:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="app">
        <select v-on:change="indexChanged">
            <option>zero</option>
            <option>one</option>
        </select>
        <select v-on:change="indexChanged">
            <option>zero</option>
            <option>one</option>
        </select>
        Index stored in vue-app: {{ index }}
    </div>

    <script>
        let app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                index: 0,
            },
            methods: {
                indexChanged: function(event) {
                    this.index = event.target.selectedIndex;
                    const selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
                    for (let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
                        selects[i].selectedIndex = this.index;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm aware that I could make the connection over the `select`s' `value` properties, which store the selected `option`s' text with `v-model`, but this wouldn't be unambiguous if multiple `option`s had the same text, which (shouldn't, yeah, but) might happen in my case. Is it in fact not possible to bind `selectedIndex`, because one shouldn't do it since the `option`s' texts should always be unique? I'd be grateful for advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set a unique value for `option` equal to the array index. Example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="app">
        <select v-model="selectIndex">
            <option v-for="(item, index) in options" :key="index" :value="index">{{ item }}</option>
        </select>
        <select v-model="selectIndex">
            <option v-for="(item, index) in options" :key="index" :value="index">{{ item }}</option>
        </select>
        Index stored in vue-app: {{ selectIndex }}
    </div>

    <script>
        let app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                selectIndex: 0,
                options: ['zero', 'one']
            }
        });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that I can change a `select`'s value by setting its `option`s' values! I wouldn't even have thought about it because I would have expected that the text gets overwritten as well that way. But what does `:key="index"` do? I can even leave it out and your code still works, so what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @S818, `:key` is recommended to be set so that Vue can uniquely identify objects. You can read about it [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Also thanks again for your answer, which I am going to accept now, since plenty of time has passed for others to post answers.